# Design pattern to store data from different sources in one object

Tags: design-patterns, format, adapter, blockchain

I'm working on a blockchain (hyperledger indy) project to store verifiable claims ([more detail](https://www.w3.org/TR/verifiable-claims-data-model/)) about transcripts etc. in the chain. 
I've different providers of the student data and they all use their own format for the data in which they deliver it to me. 
I personally thought about some kind of an adapter pattern but would like to hear other opinions about this situation. In the example below I try to make the situation clear and show the, for example, two different formats.

The goal is to store these responses into one object to be able to save it in the chain

```
{
  "student": "xxx",
  "grades": {
    "english": 9,
  }
}


<students>
    <student>
        <name>
        xxx
    </name>
        <age>
        17
    </age>
    </student>
</students>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a class that selects an appropriate parser based on the format of the data. For example, suppose there are two formats in which the student data can appear: (1) JSON and (2) XML:

```
public class Student {
    // ...
}

public interface StudentParser {
    public Student parse(String data);
}

public class JsonStudentParser {

    @Override
    public Student parse(String data) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class XmlStudentParser {

    @Override
    public Student parse(String data) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class StudentDeserializer {

    private final StudentParser jsonParser = new JsonStudentParser();
    private final StudentParser xmlParser = new XmlStudentParser();

    public Student deserialize(String data) {

        if (isJson(data)) {
            return jsonParser.parse(data);
        }
        else if (isXml(data)) {
            return xmlParser.parse(data);
        }
        else {
            throw new UnknownStudentFormatException();
        }
    }
}

public class UnknownStudentFormatException extends RuntimeException {
    // ...
}
```

I have left the decision for differentiating between JSON and XML data up to you, but the structure is the important part in the above. There is a `StudentParser` for each of the formats available in the system and the correct `StudentParser` is selected based on which format is discovered. I'm not sure if there is an official name for a pattern like this, but I have heard it referred to as a **Switchboard** before.

---

**More Advanced**

If you want the `StudentDeserializer` more generic (not dependent on JSON and XML only), you can move the logic for deciding which format a `StudentParser` implementation can handle from the `StudentDeserializer` to the implementation itself. Then, the `StudentDeserializer` can contain a list of `StudentParser` objects, which are registered, and select one that can be used to parse the data. For example (`Student` and `UnknownStudentFormatException` are the same as the previous example and have been omitted):

```
public interface StudentParser {
    public Student parse(String data);
    public boolean canHandle(String data);
}

public class JsonStudentParser {

    @Override
    public Student parse(String data) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(String data) {
        // ... is JSON? ...
    }
}

public class XmlStudentParser {

    @Override
    public Student parse(String data) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(String data) {
        // ... is XML? ...
    }
}

public class StudentDeserializer {

    private final List<StudentParser> parsers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void registerParser(StudentParser parser) {
        parsers.add(parser);
    }

    public Student deserialize(String data) {

        return parsers.stream()
            .filter(parser -> parser.canHandle(data))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UnknownStudentFormatException())
            .parse(data);
    }
}
```

The `StudentParser` implementations can then be registered:

```
JsonStudentParser jsonParser = new JsonStudentParser();
XmlStudentParser xmlParser = new XmlStudentParser();

StudentDeserializer deserializer = new StudentDeserializer();
deserializer.registerParser(jsonParser);
deserializer.registerParser(xmlParser);

deserializer.deserialize(someData);
```

If you have some sort of Dependency Injection (DI) framework, you can autowire the `StudentParser` implementations in rather than manually registering them.